# I have to keep changing IIS every time I do a build

Tags: tfs

I am learning TFS 2010 from scratch and no doubt making every mistake in the book.
So hopefully this is a simple question to answer.
When I do a build a new directory is created on the build machine.
That means I have to go to IIS and change the physical path for the website.
I don't want to have to do that, so what should I be doing to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy new builds to a fixed directory on the machine.

Comment: What you can do is copy the build output to the application directory by modifying your build script, or create a bat file to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you go in to the the source control explorer for the build you have created and located the TFSBuild.proj, check it out and edit it. Then add at the bottom

You have to replace the areas in CAPS below, this is for the debug build, so for Release change the area in the create item from Debug to Release. I used this method that I created at work for our dev and test build servers and it works like a charm.

```
  <Target Name="AfterDropBuild">

    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToDelete Include="\\NETWORK LOCATION TO WEB DIRECTORY USED BY IIS\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" ContinueOnError="true" />

    <Message Text="My target for deployment"/>
    <CreateItem Include="$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Debug\_PublishedWebsites\WEB APPLICATION NAME\**\*.*" >
      <Output ItemName="FilesToCopy" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>

    <Copy
    SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)"
    DestinationFolder="\\NETWORK LOCATION TO WEB DIRECTORY USED BY IIS\%(RecursiveDir)"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="false"
    ContinueOnError="true"
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"/>

  </Target>
```

Comment: Made a few changes as some of the stackoverflow formatting dropped some text. Also you might wanna add in the target below the rest    <RemoveDir Directories="\\NETWORK LOCATION TO WEB DIRECTORY USED BY IIS\Debug" /> for the debug build. Change to Release for release build

Comment: Also it can be a little fiddly on the first attempt at getting this working. But once you've got it down it's easy. Just make sure to have the Debug/Release areas to the right build type that you set the build to. Obviously if you create custom build configuration in you web application you will need to instead of Debug and Release call them the same name as you custom builds.

Comment: Also if you get errors during the build, make sure the network path have permissions for network service, network and ideally the TFS AD user if you are in an AD environment.